# Generate output text from a list

Tags: jsf

I have a SEAM JSF web application with a Java back end.  I have a list of objects who has a display value which I would like to display. Since the list is retrieved from the DB, it is dynamic

```html
<s:decorate>
  <ui:define name="label">Description:</ui:define>
      <!-- foreach book in bookList -> display the description
  <h:outputText value="#{bean.bookList.book.description}"/>
      -->
</s:decorate>
```

So in a way I would like to create a sort of foreach loop for labels.

Comment: Which JSF and Seam version?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza JSF 2.5, SEAM 2.1.  I think

Comment: JSF 2.5? You must come from the future since JSF latest version is JSF 2.2.1

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Opps :P I mean JSF 2.0

Comment: Then you can use [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html). Example: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-repeat-tag-example/

Comment: Seam 2.1 ain't compatible with JSF 2, not until version Seam 2.3. So if you use seam 2.1 it is most likley jsf 1.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.bookList}" var="book">
  <h:outputText value="#{book.description}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Or `#{book.description}` directly without using `<h:outputText>`.